# How to search in a List<classtype> by dynamic field name of class in c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

This was my question, so I solved it then decided to share with everybody.

I have a list of my Drivers Class.

I load data from DB then show in datagridview:

```
 List<driver> list = DriverList();
 dgvListDrivers.DataSource = list;
```

load field names in combobox:

```
List<ColNameText> l = new List<ColNameText>();
foreach (DataGridViewColumn item in dgvListDrivers.Columns)
{
    ColNameText cnt=new ColNameText();
    cnt.colname=item.Name;
    cnt.displaytext=item.HeaderText;
    l.Add(cnt);
}
comboBoxEx1.DataSource=l.ToList();
comboBoxEx1.DisplayMember = "displaytext";
```

below is ColNameText Class Definaton:

```
class ColNameText
    {
        public string colname { get; set; }
        public string displaytext { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I want to be able to search in list by driver class properties.

There was many solutions I searched but they were not in the way which I want.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like something LINQ expressions could help with:

```
static List<T> FindWhereMemberContains<T>(this List<T> list,
    string memberName, string value)
{
    var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Predicate<T>>(Expression.Call(
        Expression.Call(Expression.PropertyOrField(p, memberName), "ToString", null),
        "Contains", null, Expression.Constant(value, typeof(string))), p);
    return list.FindAll(lambda.Compile());
}
```

With:

```
dgvListDrivers.DataSource = list.FindWhereMemberContains(p.colname, txtSearch.Text);
```

For large lists, this will be considerably faster than raw reflection; for small lists, the basic reflection (without the metaprogramming overhead) could be faster - you'd need to test.

A non-expression but still not too bad version of this might be:

```
static List<T> FindWherePropertyContains<T>(this List<T> list,
    string propertyName, string value)
{
    var property = (Func<T, object>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<T, object>),
        typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName).GetGetMethod());
    return list.FindAll(x => property(x).ToString().Contains(value));
}
```

Comment: i think your right about process time, it should be tried in huge  data. thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

so below is the simplest way you can search in your list.
this happents in a textbox_textchange event:

```
 private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var p =(ColNameText) comboBoxEx1.SelectedItem;
        var result= from q in list where q.GetType().GetProperty(p.colname).GetValue(q,null).ToString().Contains(txtSearch.Text) select q;
        dgvListDrivers.DataSource = result.ToList();

    }
```

Comment: Note: if you use raw reflection, you should *really* hoist the member lookup, i.e. `var property = typeof(driver).GetProperty(p.colname)` somewhere at the start, and use that many times; in a perfect world you'd also use `GetGetMethod()` and `Delegate.CreateDelegate` to optimize that further, but again: once only